# Optimization search problem: how to appropriately search on a list that has solutions in different regions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, search, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I have posted this on the Mathematica stack exchange without success. Apparently since it is a more generic optimization question, I guess it is appropriate for this community.

So I have this almost linear function (for evey frequency it is the square root of a sum of squares), but not quite.

```
3 \[Sqrt]((
    2.89441*10^-12 (-8.13867*10^8 f^2 (211.881 - 478.234 f^2) + 
       8000000 f^2 (9282.09 - 87779.4 f^2) (0.105449 - 
          0.10316 f^2) \[Pi]^2)^2 TolC2^2)/((211.881 - 
        478.234 f^2)^2 + 
      4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)^2 + (
    0.00536257 (-13918.7 f^2 (211.881 - 478.234 f^2) + 
       8000000 f^2 (1 - 2.03932 f^2) (0.105449 - 
          0.10316 f^2) \[Pi]^2)^2 TolL1^2)/((211.881 - 
        478.234 f^2)^2 + 
      4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)^2 + (
    0.00404897 (-5741.98 f^2 (211.881 - 478.234 f^2) + 
       8000000 f^2 (1 - 2.34693 f^2) (0.105449 - 
          0.10316 f^2) \[Pi]^2)^2 TolL3^2)/((211.881 - 
        478.234 f^2)^2 + 
      4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)^2 + (
    8024.83 (2 (211.881 - 478.234 f^2) (1 - 2.03932 f^2) + 
       13918.7 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2))^2 TolRin^2)/((211.881 - 
        478.234 f^2)^2 + 
      4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)^2 + (
    400 ((211.881 - 478.234 f^2)^2 + 
       4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2) (-((
        75 (2 (211.881 - 478.234 f^2) (1 - 2.34693 f^2) + 
           5741.98 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)))/((211.881 - 
            478.234 f^2)^2 + 
          4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)^(3/2)) + 1/
       Sqrt[(211.881 - 478.234 f^2)^2 + 
        4000000 f^2 (0.105449 - 
           0.10316 f^2)^2 \[Pi]^2])^2 TolRout^2)/(9 Log[10]^2))
```

The tolerance values can take any value from the list

```
CatalogTolerances = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01}
```

Now I have ordered all combinations of these tolerance values from the biggest sum to the lowest. Basically I want the st of bigger tolerances (that sum to a bigger number, I mean) that satisfy a condition.

To get all the combinations and ordering them I did:

```
Tolerances={TolRin,TolRout,TolL1,TolL3,TolC2};
f[v_] := Map[Apply[Rule, #] &, Transpose[{Tolerances, v}]];
ToleranceCatalogCombinations = 
  ReverseSortBy[Tuples[CatalogTolerances, Length[Tolerances]], 
   Total];
ToleranceCatalogCombinations = Map[f, ToleranceCatalogCombinations];
```

Then I want that the local maximum of this function is smaller than a certain threshold value meaning that:

[image]

I want that local maximum to be below a certain threshold. Here is an example of a solution where I wanted to find a combination of tolerances so that the threshold was 0.5. It took 3849 iterations, corresponding to the solution

```
{TolRin -> 0.2, TolL1 -> 0.02, TolL3 -> 0.03, TolC2 -> 0.03, 
 TolRout -> 0.05}
```

[image]

Now searching for every element of ToleranceCatalogCombinations becomes computationally very tedious, and takes more time than I want. I wonder if Mathematica has any function that does this easy rather than a for cycle. I have computed all the maxima

```
values = Table[0, {t, 1, Length[ToleranceCatalogCombinations]}];
For[t = 1, t <= Length[ToleranceCatalogCombinations], t++,
  target = CircuitSigma3Gain /. ToleranceCatalogCombinations[[t]];
  values[[t]] = MaxValue[{target, 0 <= f <= (0.9*fP)/1000}, f];
  ];
values
```

And there seem to be regions where the function is going up and down around certain values. So maybe the computation effort can be reduced without much harm?

I have thought maybe I could try the fixed combinations:

```
A={0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
B={0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}
C={0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}
D={0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03}
E={0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02}
F={0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01}
```

And see ok, if it satisfies the condition in set E but it does not satisfy in set D, an optimal solution might lie between set D and set E. Because while I have used the criteria of ordering the setsfrom bigger sum to lower, from a practical perspective it might be more interesting to find a more consistent solution, without a tolerance of 0.01 and one of 0.2 coexisting. In that case the problem becomes searching on a set of 2^5=32 possible solutions instead of 6^5=7776 solutions. But there might be something I am overlooking in this approach... Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: *"takes more time than I want"* How long does it take?

Comment: It takes hours @Olivier

Comment: Doing the symbolic optimization is really slow then. Perhaps you should check a few interesting frequencies numerically to discard obviously infeasible combinations and then do the expensive test on the best of what's left.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating CircuitSigma3Gain is the bottleneck.
The location of maxima is not affected, if you drop the outermost 3 Sqrt. Converting denominators and numerators of the expresion to HornerForm helps. Using a compiled function (and parallel execution) will speed thing up.

Using

```
(Block[{q = Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[#1]]}, 
Divide @@ (HornerForm[#1, fs] & ) /@ q] & )[Factor @*Together /@ (CircuitSigma3Gain /. f^(k_) :> fs^(k/2))]
```

and building a compiled function with this expression leads to a duration of 1½ minutes to determine the maxima with

```
lmax = ParallelMap[3 Sqrt[#] & /@
FindMaxValue[{alfsqc[f, #1], .001 < f < .9}, {f, .7}] &, 
ToleranceCatalogCombinations] // Flatten;
```

at my computer (Ryzen 7 2700X, 3850MHz, 8 Mathematica-Kernels).
*alfsqc* means "almost linear function squared compiled".
Please note the usage of the numeric FindMaxValue in place of the symbolic funtion MaxValue.

With the list *lmax* it is easy to find the sets of tolerance for which the local maximum passes some test:

```
passedtest = Position[lmax, x_ /; x <= 1/2] // Flatten;
```

[the first and the last set of tol. passing the test max < 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpdGU.png)

Comment: Hi @Peter! Thank you for your contribution. Would it be possible for you to go through with more detail in your code? Just what you are doing, exactly. Thank you!

Comment: As this is not the Mathematica board, I suggest you get my Notebook (Mathematica 11.2) at this link [link](https://mega.nz/file/fWpASBCB#IIFOe4IWwdiDatdQJHaf50cfOfRVdOsRpGa0m6lexl0)